# AWS Athena (Presto) how to transpose map where the values are an array to rows

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to flatten a complex structure on Athena

A row in my table looks like

| id | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 2003301084 | {repeats=[3], copayment=[CoPayment, other], concessionalstatus=[E, T], prescriberdate=[2014-06-29], previouspurchasesonsamescript=[0], age=[49], numberofscripts=[1]} |

I would like to go to:

| id | tag | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2003301084 | repeats | 3 |
| 2003301084 | copayment | CoPayment |
| 2003301084 | copayment | other |
| 2003301084 | concessionalstatus | E |
| 2003301084 | concessionalstatus | T |
| 2003301084 | prescriberdate | 2014-06-29 |
| 2003301084 | previouspurchasesonsamescript | 0 |
| 2003301084 | age | 49 |
| 2003301084 | numberofscripts | 1 |

I cannot find an example that goes this deep into the structure

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UNNEST`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html?highlight=unnest#unnest) to extract the map key/value pairs into separate rows and then to extract the individual array elements into separate rows:

```sql
WITH data(id, tags) AS
(
    VALUES (
        2003301084,
        map_from_entries(array[
            row('repeats', array['3']),
            row('copayment', array['CoPayment', 'other']),
            row('concessionalstatus', array['E', 'T']),
            row('prescriberdate', array['2014-06-29']),
            row('previouspurchasesonsamescript', array['0']),
            row('age', array['49']),
            row('numberofscripts', array['1'])
        ])
    )
),
arrays AS (
    SELECT id, tag, entries
    FROM data CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tags) AS m(tag, entries)
)
SELECT id, tag, value
FROM arrays CROSS JOIN UNNEST(entries) AS a(value)
```

=>

```
     id     |              tag              |   value
------------+-------------------------------+------------
 2003301084 | repeats                       | 3
 2003301084 | copayment                     | CoPayment
 2003301084 | copayment                     | other
 2003301084 | concessionalstatus            | E
 2003301084 | concessionalstatus            | T
 2003301084 | prescriberdate                | 2014-06-29
 2003301084 | previouspurchasesonsamescript | 0
 2003301084 | age                           | 49
 2003301084 | numberofscripts               | 1
(9 rows)
```